# Como usar Resources em arquivo .js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, resources

Tenho um projeto **Asp.Net MVC** onde estou usando **Resources**, e para usa-lo em minhas **páginas web** é fácil!

```
@using projeto.Translations

<h3>@Resources.DISPLAY_OLA</h3>
```

O problema é que tenho alguns itens (botões, por exemplo) que estão definidos em um arquivo **.js** e preciso adicionar os **Resources** a eles também. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma é você definir essas *strings* no seu layout, por exemplo na tag `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var DISPLAY_OLA = "@Resources.DISPLAY_OLA";
    </script>
</head>
```

Mas isso não é tão *elegante*. Então outra forma é você criar um script externo dinâmico, como explicado [nesse link](http://blog.pmunin.com/2013/04/dynamic-javascript-css-in-aspnet-mvc.html), que resumindo:

Você cria uma view `Resources.js.cshtml`. Nessa view você cria todos os resources que você precisa, da mesma forma que mostrei acima. Depois referencia na tag script:

```
<script src="@Url.Action("ResourcesJS")"></script>
```

Assim, com as variáveis declaradas de forma global, você pode acessa-las em qualquer script. Muitas vezes não é recomendável usar variáveis globais, mas acho que nesse caso é útil. O que pode ser feito é criar os resources em um único objeto(que é como eu faço em um dos projetos onde trabalho):

```
var Lang = {
    DISPLAY_OLA: "@Resources.DISPLAY_OLA"
};
```

Concentrando todos os resources no objeto global `Lang` você tem apenas uma variável global.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

você já tentou algo como:

```
var globalResource = '<%= Resources.MyClass.ResourceKeyValue %>';
```

Comment: Sim amigo, mas o conteúdo da variável recebe a string de forma literal (como está escrita na frente dela) .

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma label e atribuir ao text algo como

```
text='<%= Resources.MyClass.ResourceKeyValue %>'
```

Ou por exemplo...

```
<dx:ASPxLabel ID="myLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:TextResource,  SuaPalavra %>" />
```